# instagram api return not square photos with white lines

Tags: instagram-api

I posted not square photo in instagram
https://instagram.com/p/7M7aBoNTcM/

By instagram api using 
https_//api.instagram.com/v1/media/1061415553965831926_2141618404?access_token=Token tried to get all photos and I have for that image the next standard_resolution url:
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1//t51.2885-15//s640x640//sh0.08//e35//11821940_708988202567623_81870409_n.jpg

There are not param for cropping, but I got my image with white lines at the top and at the bottom of image.

Why on the instagram's web site my image as I sent(rectangular), but api returns square with white lines?

How I can post not square pictures for getting them without white lines?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Sept. 4th 2015 Update:

As of Sept. 3rd 2015, [instagram now allows API clients to get the images in their original aspect ratio](http://developers.instagram.com/post/128288227716/api-migration-for-landscape-and-portrait-formats) (i.e. rectangular for Landscapes, Portraits) and will not crop them, if you updated a new setting in the API Client.

#### Steps:

1. Login to  into your client application settings on https://instagram.com/developer/
2. Click **Manage Clients** on top nav menu.
3. Locate your API Client, and click **Edit**.
4. Click the **Migrations** Tab for your API Client application, and check the box that says "Non square media".
5. Click Update Client.

[image]

That's it! Now when you get the images from the API endpoints, the portraits, landscapes that were uploaded will not be cropped to square images, and the originals will be returned.

Related Blog Post: [API migration for landscape and portrait formats](http://developers.instagram.com/post/128288227716/api-migration-for-landscape-and-portrait-formats)

#### Previous Answer (Deprecated. Don't read unless you want box square and landscape / portrait versions at the same time)

As far as I can tell, Instagram has not updated their API to return the original images in various sizes for the new Landscape / Portrait upload feature they rolled out recently.

There is a -- for lack of a better word - "***workaround***" that you can use to get the original uncropped landscape  / portrait images from the square images returned by the api for your landscape  / portrait photo.

Here's how.

Take the Thumbnail image URL returned by the API. In your case, the URL returned is `https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c257.0.565.565/11375403_666004300168456_93194657_n.jpg`

[image]

If you remove the last url segment before the image name, i.e. `/c257.0.565.565` you will get the url for the landscape thumbnail. (see below)

[image]

#### Here's how you get the other 2 sizes in their original aspect ratio.

Now using this new url that has the last url segment removed,

- if you replace Thumbnail Returned by API (cropped / with white borders)
  `s150x150` with `s320x320` you will be the low resolution landscape image url and
- if you replace Thumbnail Returned by API (cropped / with white borders) `s150x150` with `s640x640` you will get the standard resolution landscape image.

You can programatically do all this after getting the thumbnail url from the API.

Like I said before, this is a ***workaround*** until Instagram officially updates their API and exposes these additional images.

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c257.0.565.565/11375403_666004300168456_93194657_n.jpg

#### Thumbnail Landscape (uncropped)

`https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11375403_666004300168456_93194657_n.jpg`

[image: Thumbnail Landscape uncropped]

#### Low Resolution Landscape (uncropped)

`https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11375403_666004300168456_93194657_n.jpg`
[[image: Low Resolution landscape uncropped][2](https://instagram.com/developer/)

#### Standard Resolution Landscape (uncropped)

`https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e35/11375403_666004300168456_93194657_n.jpg`

[image: Standard Resolution Landscape]

Comment: I did all what you mentioned in the steps, but I'm still getting images with a white border. Do I have to reregister the client?

Comment: I'm also getting images with large white borders. However, this is only on the 640 x 640 size. Any images that are smaller than that show up in the original portrait/landscape dimensions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more.  The url format has changed.